# Weighted average grouping by date (in index) in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, weighted-average

I need some help trying to obtain a weighted average for a column, based on datetime-index and another 'mass' column.
For example:

```
d = {'date': ['2021-08-01 12:00:00', '2021-08-01 13:00:00', '2021-08-01 14:00:00', '2021-08-02 15:00:00', '2021-08-02 16:00:00', '2021-08-02 17:00:00'], 
     'mass': [23,   40,  10,  12,  15,  11], 
     '%':    [0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.set_index('date')
```

What I need is to obtain the weighted average of '%' every 2 hours, being 'mass' the column of weights.

I need the output to be like this:

```
date(index)         | mass |  %
2021-08-01 13:00:00 |  43  | 0.865
2021-08-02 15:00:00 |  22  | 0.464
2021-08-02 17:00:00 |  26  | 0.454
```

Being '%' calculated as weighted average:

```
0.865 = ((23 x 0.4) + (40 x 0.7))/ (40 + 23)
```

Please note that I may not have continuous datetimes in index, for example, I could skip several hours because of lack of data, or even days. In that case, I need the output to be NaN if there is no data to calculate with.
In case there is only one row of data, assume that row to be the weighted average for the period...

Periods may vary as well, from 2 hours to 12 months...

On a previous question, someone already helped me with this:

```
out = df.assign(k=df['mass'].mul(df['%']))[['mass','k']].sum(level=0)
out['%'] = out.pop('k').div(out['mass'])
```

Though, this works only when I have repeated indexes and this time this is not the case.

Comment: How should we determine interval start & end. What I mean is why the expected output starts with 13:00:00 and not 12:00:00. Please provide this information for probable dataframes.

Comment: interval of start & end is given by the start and end of the day... always start at 00:00 and end at 23:00. Generally I will need to group by day or every 4 or 8 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try grouping every 2 hours and you will get closer -

```
d = {'date': ['2021-08-01 12:00:00', '2021-08-01 13:00:00', '2021-08-01 14:00:00', '2021-08-02 15:00:00', '2021-08-02 16:00:00', '2021-08-02 17:00:00'], 
     'mass': [23,   40,  10,  12,  15,  11], 
     '%':    [0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 0.1, 0.2, 0.8]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('date')

df['mass_wt'] = df['mass'] * df['%']
op = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='2H')).agg({'mass': 'sum', 'mass_wt': 'sum'}).query('mass > 0')
op['op'] = op['mass_wt'] / op['mass']
```

Comment: is it possible to help me trying to set an offset of 5 hours per day... meaning that my day should start at 5am instead of at 00:00 ?